# muted header video in html5

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I want to add a muted video in header with full width but `300px` height.

The problem I'm facing is when I reduce the height of the video the width reduces automatically whereas I want width to be full.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<video id="videobcg" preload="auto"
  autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted" volume="0">
  <source src="http://12982-presscdn-0-38.pagely.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/2016-web-loop-03.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Here is the CSS part:

```
#videobcg { 
   position: relative;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   min-width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
   width: 800px;
   height: 380px;
   z-index: -1000;
   overflow: hidden;
   -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
   -moz-filter: blur(5px);
   -o-filter: blur(5px);
   -ms-filter: blur(5px);
   filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Comment: How should the video behave when you change the ratio of the player?

Comment: It should take full screen width but a few lines of height. @Huelfe

Comment: this would mean that you cut some height information of the video, right?

Comment: Yes this would be fine @Huelfe

Comment: No such thing as `-ms-filter`. Your video won't have any blur on IE.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's what you want.

```css
#videobcg { 
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   min-height: 50%;
   min-width: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
   height: 380px;
   z-index: -1000;
   overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  object-fit: fill;
}

.video-button{
  position:relative;
  z-index:3;
  margin-left:40%;
  margin-top:40%;
}
```

```html
<video id="videobcg" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop"
muted="muted" volume="0"> <source
src="http://12982-presscdn-0-38.pagely.netdna-cdn.com/wp-
content/uploads/2016/03/2016-web-loop-03.mp4"
type="video/mp4"> <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm"> </video>

<div class=video-button>
   <a href="#" class="button">Button</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't respect the video's aspect ratio.

Comment: He didn't want to

Comment: How can i add a button on this video that will direct me to some other part of page ? @l.g.karolos

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
#videobcg { 
   position: relative;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
   max-width: 800px;
   height: 380px;
   z-index: -1000;
   overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Comment: No this changes nothing.